# how delete spaces in a data (database) after a word

Tags: c#, database, mdf

I have a problem.. When I recup the information in my database, I have a lot of blanks after my word because the size in the cells is 10 and I have a word with a size of 3 (example: "abc" and I recup the world "abc       ").

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are saving text data in fix length data types like `char`. Try to use a variable length datatype like `nvarchar`. You can also use trim functions to remove spaces in the select like

```
select LTRIM(RTRIM(myColumn)) from myTable
```

You can also remove the spaces after the database layer, with c# `String.Trim` function like this: `"my string   ".Trim();`

Comment: That is the solution ! Thanks !!!

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct and vote for it. Thanks!